# Nginx proxy pass php index problems

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, directoryindex

I am having slight issues making my indexes work with nginx serving static content and passing php to apache on a different server.

Basically if I need it to try index.php on the backend apache server when xxx.co.uk/ is requested. If no index.php or index.html exists on the nginx server i get 403 Forbidden. If i request xxx.co.uk/index.php behaviour is as expected and apache serves the page.

Could anyone suggest a solution to this? My initial thoughts was using try_files - but exactly how I am unsure - my tinkering didn't work!

I hope I have been clear, if not then please ask and I will try to elaborate further.

Nginx settings:

```
server
{
   listen 80;
   server_name www.xxx.co.uk xxx.co.uk;
   access_log /srv/www/xxx.co.uk/logs/access.log;
   error_log /srv/www/xxx.co.uk/logs/error.log;

   root /srv/www/xxx.co.uk/public_html;

   index index.php index.html;

   # deny access to apache .htaccess files
   location ~ /\.ht
   {
        deny all;
   }

   location ~* ^.*\.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.6:80;
    }   
}
```

and apache:

```
 <VirtualHost 192.168.0.6:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.co.uk
     ServerName xxx.co.uk
     ServerAlias xxx.co.uk www.xxx.co.uk
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxx.co.uk/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/xxx.co.uk/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/xxx.co.uk/logs/access.log combined
     DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I should also note if I place a blank index.php on the nginx server, it will work as required. The blank nginx index.php is ignored and the apache2 index.php is served. However this isn't ideal as I don't want to have to place blank 'dummy' files in every directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `try_files` and a `location` to put it in.

Example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Not had chance to try yet, when I do I will feedback and accept if it works :) Thanks!

Comment: Just tried this, got rid of the index line and used

 location / {
  try_files index.php index.html/ =404;
 }

Instead of 403 I now get 404. Obviously it is trying the nginx server for index.php, how would I make it try the apache server/make it follow the proxy pass rule?

Comment: Why did you get rid of the `index` line? That would certainly cause it to fail.

Comment: the outcome with or without appears to be the same - it still doesn't try the proxy server for the .php file.